# Cannot connect to mssql db using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, freetds, pymssql

I have FreeTDS installed and configured correctly. My freetds.conf file as this appended to the end:

```
[myserver]
    host = myserver
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
```

And I can running the following command gives me a SQL prompt:

```
tsql -S myserver -U username
```

My python script is extremely minimal, in an attempt to successfully connect to the database:

```
#! /path/to/python/bins

import pymsql
conn = pymssql.connect(host='myserver', user='username', password='password', database='database', as_dict=True)
conn.close()
```

But when I run it I recieve the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    conn = pymssql.connect(host='myserver', user='username', password='password', database='database', as_dict=True)
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 456, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:6017)
pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.
```

What could cause this? From what I've searched, most people who run into this problem have the freetds.conf file configured incorrectly; however, I can successfully connect (with tsql). Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just looked through `pymssql` code and most likely you have problem with MSSQL driver. https://code.google.com/p/pymssql/source/browse/pymssql.pyx?name=1.9.908#456

Try configuring logging in FreeTDS to see "unknown reason": see http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/logging.htm ([mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20150403090737/http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/logging.htm))

Basically:

```
$ export TDSDUMP=/tmp/freetds.log
```

Comment: It looks like it isn't trying to connect on the port I specified in the freetds.conf file: `net.c:210:Connecting to <server-ip> port 4000 (TDS version 5.0)`

Comment: I figured out one way to get a connection (although I am now getting other errors); I just need to specify the port in the python code. So where I have `host=myserver`, I would have `host=myserver:port`. Although all of my problems aren't solved, the one I was asking about is. Thanks!

Comment: I should also note that I had to create the following env variable: `TDSVER=8.0`