# Can I use a config file to hold connection string parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymssql

I have a script which connects to a database. I'd like to pull out the server,user,password,db from the script and put it into a config file. I'm successfully pulling in the values from the config file. The problem I'm having is the pymssql.connect fails when I have variables in the syntax. I pasted my sample code below. Is this possible?

```
###database connection  
config = configparser.ConfigParser()  
config.read('test.config')  
server = config['DEFAULT']['SQLServer']  
db = config['DEFAULT']['Database']  
user = config['DEFAULT']['User']  
password = config['DEFAULT']['Password']  

###this works  
####conn = pymssql.connect(host='Server1', user='Joe',password='MyPass', database='MyDB')

###this doesn't
try:
    conn = pymssql.connect(host=server, user=user,password=password, database=db)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Run this in a shell and ensure that the values you've read from the config file are accurate.

Comment: The values are what I expect them to be.  When I run it from the console I get this: "'Server1'", "'Joe'", "'MyPass'", "'MyDB'". Would those extra quotes cause a problem?

Comment: Could you paste the full error?

Comment: From the console: >>> conn = pymssql.connect(server,user,password,db)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 595, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:9251)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1829, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:19198)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 597, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:5868)
_mssql.MSSQLDriverException: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    conn = pymssql.connect(server,user,password,db)
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 602, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:9370)
pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.

Comment: I found [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150524/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-via-pymssql) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662680/cannot-connect-to-mssql-db-using-pymssql) questions that have the same error you do; hopefully they help.

Comment: I don't believe those apply. I am running on windows, and not running Free TDS

Comment: Trailing blanks in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I retrieved connection properties and connected sql server database

```
**App.ini file**

[CoreContext]
host=sservername.database.windows.net
user=dbuser@servername
password=password
database=DeltaXCore



**Connection.py file**

appConfig = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
appConfig.read("App.ini")
ConnectionString.HOST = appConfig.get("CoreContext", "host")
CoreConnectionString.USER = appConfig.get("CoreContext", "user")
CoreConnectionString.PASSWORD = appConfig.get("CoreContext", "password")
CoreConnectionString.DATABASE = appConfig.get("CoreContext", "database")



pymssql.connect(host=objdeltaxConnectionString.HOST, user=objdeltaxConnectionString.USER,password=objdeltaxConnectionString.PASSWORD, database=objdeltaxConnectionString.DATABASE)
```